# Template Toolkit: how return a hash from a MACRO BLOCK

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Is it possible to write macros or blocks that return a hash to the caller?

I tried to modularize some template code:

```
[%- 
MACRO MakeSomeThing(something) BLOCK;
  s = {  a => 'a',
         b => something,
         c => 'c'
      };
  # RETURN s;  # not allowed
  # s;         # just returns the hash ref string (HASH(0x32e42e4))
END;


  newOb =  MakeSomeThing('foo');
  dumper.dump({'newOb' => newOb});
%]
```

Is there some way to implement a similar pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not find a way when I was faced with the same problem.

As a workaround, you can pass in a reference and have the macro modify the referenced variable. This works for both arrays and hashes.

Example definition:

```
[%
   # usage: newOb={}; MakeSomeThing(newOb, something)
   MACRO MakeSomeThing(rv, something) BLOCK;
      rv.a = 'a';
      rv.b = something;
      rv.c = 'c';
   END;
%]
```

Example use:

```
[%
   newOb = {};
   MakeSomeThing(newOb, 'foo');
   dumper.dump({'newOb' => newOb});
%]
```

Comment: yes - this is the way i did it as workaround (beside that i just import the created hash in the given one)