# How to return values from Perl block in template toolkit

Tags: perl, templates, template-toolkit

I am working on template toolkit script. My script needs to convert a hexadecimal number to binary number and need to apply that binary number for i2c programming. I am stuck to return binary value and use those bits to program i2c.

```
[% MACRO i2c_write(rv,address,data) PERL -%]
my %rv;
my $address = hex($stash->get('address'));
my $data = hex($stash->get('data'));
my $bin_add = sprintf("%08b",$address);
my $bin_data = sprintf("%08b",$data);
$rv{bin_address} = $bin_add;
$rv{bin_data} = $bin_data;
[% END -%]

[% i2c_write(bin_value,'0x10','0x3B') %]

Expected output:
bin_value.bin_address = 00010000
bin_value.bin_data    = 00111011
```

I want to parse this bin_value.bin_address and bin_value.bin_data to another MACRO (still writing the MACRO).

In Another MACRO, will take each bit and print each bit

Comment: When you call the macro `i2c_write(bin_value,'0x10','0x3B')`, what is `bin_value` ? Is it supposed to be the string "bin_value" or something else? Please provide a complete minimal example: See [mcve] for more information

Comment: In one of the stack overflow question, there was a workaround to return hash from a MACRO block. I used same methodology. Please refer the below link                                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762573/template-toolkit-how-return-a-hash-from-a-macro-block.

Comment: bin_value is the hash which return values from the i2c_write MACRO. In bin_value the keys are bin_add and bin_data and values are respective binary values

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to pass the name of a hash to the macro and store the values inside that hash. You can use the stash for that, for example:

**p.pl**:

```
use v5.38;
use Template;

my $template = Template->new({
    INCLUDE_PATH => '.',  # or specify your own directory
    EVAL_PERL    => 1,    # enable Perl code in template
});
my $vars = {
    bin_value => {
        bin_address => '',
        bin_data => '',
    }
};
$template->process('example.tt', $vars) || die $template->error();
```

**example.tt**:

```
[% MACRO i2c_write(rv_name, address, data) PERL -%]
    my $hash_name = $stash->get('rv_name');
    my $rv =  $stash->get($hash_name);
    my $address = hex($stash->get('address'));
    my $data = hex($stash->get('data'));
    $rv->{bin_address} = sprintf("%08b", $address);
    $rv->{bin_data} = sprintf("%08b", $data);
[% END -%]
[% i2c_write('bin_value', '0x10', '0x3B') -%]
[% bin_value.bin_address %]
```

**Output**:

```
00010000
```

Comment: When i use  [% bin_value.bin_address %] after i2c_write MACRO i am unable to get any value. how to get bin_value.bin_address outside the MACRO